# SQL queries from an external DB in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Actually I have a php website in my hosting. Now I am personalizing a Wordpress theme to replace it. It's all ok for now, but the old website has a built in function to connect to another database with a token. This connection is only to get some data.

Can you tell me how to implement this in my new wordpress theme?
Did a wordpress plugin exists for this?

Thanks

Comment: Gracias a ti. Thanks.

Comment: what database? where? WP is nailed at the hips to mysql, generally, and won't know how to talk to a "foreign" db, especially if the old site is using vendor extensions in the sql syntax.

Comment: @MarcB If you look at the tags it's **Mysql** related database. With this trick you can use any query and work on it with php. I have done this before many times.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: doesn't mean much. WP implies mysql, but "external database" DOESN'T

Comment: @MarcB Ok if you say it, then… The OP is satisfy with my answer, for his needs. That is the main purpose here. You can use WP API for all other cases or build a special plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to connect wordpress to a second database *(without a token)* is to add this little piece of code (replacing strings by your connexion data) :

```
$wpdb2 = new WPDB( 'remote_user', 'remote_password', 'remote_db', 'remote_server');
```

Then you can use this new object to query anything that you want to, just like the main $wpdb object. You can use this on the function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

I think that maybe there is some plugins, for this kind of purpose… You will have to search.

Reference: [Using wpdb to connect to a separate database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1618/79855)

Comment: Does this work with a sqlserver database? Or only with mySQL?

Comment: @BennettForkner This works for wordpress and all databases that wordpress allow.