# How to receive the data from WooCommerce API Webhooks

Tags: json, wordpress, api, woocommerce, webhooks

Delivery method is Post with a secret;
Delivery url: `www.domain2.com/wc_back.php`.
The data is json:

```
{
    "order":{
        "id":623,
        "order_number":623,
        "order_key":"wc_order_57224dc67c4ec",
        "created_at":"2016-04-28T17:52:06Z",
        "updated_at":"2016-04-28T17:52:06Z",
        "completed_at":"2016-04-28T17:52:06Z",
        "status":"on-hold",
        "currency":"USD",
        "total":"23.00",
        "subtotal":"23.00",
        "total_line_items_quantity":1,
        "total_tax":"0.00",
        "total_shipping":"0.00",
        "cart_tax":"0.00",
        "shipping_tax":"0.00",
        "total_discount":"0.00",
        "shipping_methods":"",
        "payment_details":{
            "method_id":"bacs",
            "method_title":"u4ebau6c11u5e01u4ed8u6b3euff08u5faeu4fe1/u652fu4ed8u5b9duff09",
            "paid":false
        },
        "billing_address":{
            "first_name":"test",
            "last_name":"test",
            "company":"",
            "address_1":"",
            "address_2":"",
            "city":"",
            "state":"",
            "postcode":"",
            "country":"US",
            "email":"test@163.com",
            "phone":""
        },
        "shipping_address":{
            "first_name":"test",
            "last_name":"test",
            "company":"",
            "address_1":"",
            "address_2":"",
            "city":"",
            "state":"",
            "postcode":"",
            "country":"US"
        },
        "note":"",
        "customer_ip":"192.200.194.126",
        "customer_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36",
        "customer_id":0,
        "view_order_url":"http://www.domain.com/my-account/view-order/623",
        "line_items":[
            {
                "id":151,
                "subtotal":"23.00",
                "subtotal_tax":"0.00",
                "total":"23.00",
                "total_tax":"0.00",
                "price":"23.00",
                "quantity":1,
                "tax_class":null,
                "name":"u5251u7075u7f8eu670du91d1u5e01100G",
                "product_id":26,
                "sku":"bnsus100g",
                "meta":[

                ]
            }
        ],
        "shipping_lines":[

        ],
        "tax_lines":[

        ],
        "fee_lines":[

        ],
        "coupon_lines":[

        ],
        "customer":{
            "id":0,
            "email":"test@163.com",
            "first_name":"test",
            "last_name":"test",
            "billing_address":{
                "first_name":"test",
                "last_name":"test",
                "company":"",
                "address_1":"",
                "address_2":"",
                "city":"",
                "state":"",
                "postcode":"",
                "country":"US",
                "email":"test@163.com",
                "phone":""
            },
            "shipping_address":{
                "first_name":"test",
                "last_name":"test",
                "company":"",
                "address_1":"",
                "address_2":"",
                "city":"",
                "state":"",
                "postcode":"",
                "country":"US"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the data on another website `www.domain2.com/wc_back.php`. 
I don't know how, and I need someone help me to make it.

I want to receive the data stored into a txt file as formatted json variables.
 
If you need a recompense, we can negotiate it.

Comment: The txt file looks like an export order file from a woocommerce web site. Is your second web site a woocommerce website or an app? How do you generate this txt file? If I understand, you would like to re-import that data on this second website when a "complete" order is generated on the first web site, triggered by some function or hook? — There is also [**others ways**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751938/get-query-from-an-external-db-in-wordpress/36759606#36759606) to get something like this.

Comment: Well, the second web site is not woocommerce, it is my own website. By the way, what is your others ways?