# Wordpress connect external database and get information

Tags: database, api, wordpress-rest-api

"Ok, will try to summarize so it doesn't end-up being a mess of a question.
I have a wordpress site, and i want to get information from my other site database to show in the wordpress one. What is the best way for me to do this?"

Comment: Just export the db and import the SQL file via PHPMyadmin, or even better clone the old site using a plugin like Duplicator, which will do that for you and copy everything else as well.

Comment: the problem is the old one is still active and will be still, the thing i want to do is for the user in the wordpress site to input data and this will check with the other site which is a backoffice so to say.

Comment: Hmm, in that case maybe looking into WP multisite functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing and the best way I found is to use PHP code (may be with plugin like "Insert PHP Code Snippet").

The important thing, it's that WP don't use PDO like PHP classic website, but is own connection method : WPDB.

See the doc : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

And see also this topic : [Get query from an external DB in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751938/get-query-from-an-external-db-in-wordpress)

Hope this helps