# Woocommerce feed products from Sql Server Database

Tags: php, sql-server, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is it possible to query a remote SQL Server database to fetch products, images and to store orders? Can I call directly a `Select` query for example to get the products' info and create the products using Woocommerce functions?

**Edit**
I tried to use `$wpdb` with SQL Server credentials but didn't work. It looks like `$wpdb` only accepts MySql Databases. Is there another way? Or I have to use pure php?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry but WooCommerce (and Wordpress plugin) questions are off topic on  WordPress Development StackExchange… So this question is in the right place here on StackOverFlow.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec something being for off-topic for one community doesn't make it on topic for another. There is nothing about this question that is about programming, and I assume (as it appears you marked my comment as no longer required) that you also suggest that talking to the developer of said add-on is not correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about programming, but about how a Wordpress Add-On functions, or how to add functionality to it. If you have attempted to amend the add-on to provide the functionality you require, then include the code you have used, and explain why it isn't working.

Comment: You can use something like in this thread: [SQL queries from an external DB in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36759606/3730754)

Comment: @Larnu it stackoverflow for coding questions only? It is a question regarding the capabilities of a php framework/cms like wordpress.

Comment: Asking if an applicationle is capable of doing something is not on topic for Stack Overflow, no, @netdev . From the [tour]: *"Don't ask about... Anything not directly related to writing computer programs"* You're not asking how to write it here, with evidence of your attempts, just if it can be done.